# SCSS generated CSS has 'NULNULNULNULNUL' at the bottom of CSS file

Tags: sass, compass-sass

I'm using SASS preprocessor, when the css is generated I have a line of NUL at the bottom of the file.. has anyone come across this or knows how to resolve it?

I use grunt to compile the sass to css.. as seen in this block..

```
        compass: {
        dist: {
            options: {
                require: 'rgbapng',
                sassDir: 'assets/sass',
                environment: 'production',
                cssDir: 'assets/stylesheets',
                imagesDir: 'assets/images',
                httpPath: "assets/",
                assetCacheBuster: true,
                noLineComments: true,
                relativeAssets: true,
                boring: false,
                debugInfo: true,
                outputStyle: 'compressed',
                // CSS output mode. Can be: nested, expanded, compact, compressed.
                // Please see http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#output_style
                // for descriptions of the options available
                raw: 'preferred_syntax = :scss\n'
            }
        },
        dev: {
            options: {
                require: 'rgbapng',
                sassDir: 'assets/sass',
                environment: 'development',
                cssDir: 'assets/stylesheets',
                imagesDir: 'assets/images',
                httpPath: "assets/",
                assetCacheBuster: true,
                noLineComments: true,
                relativeAssets: true,
                boring: false,
                debugInfo: false,
                outputStyle: 'expanded',
                // CSS output mode. Can be: nested, expanded, compact, compressed.
                raw: 'preferred_syntax = :scss\n'
            }
        }
    },
```

[image]

Comment: Try getting it to recompile.  It happens every once in a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it was because I was using a server elsewhere rather than a local development environment, later on I was getting files cut off that were being submitted to our SVN.